# No notifications are shown when using rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I created a new folder in my inbox and some rules to receive mails from my team in it.

What I noticed is that I don't receive notifications (the small rectangle in the bottom right of the screen) when I recieve a mail from them.

Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a notification on your incoming mails *within* the rule.

- Open Menu > Tools > Rules...
- Highlight the rule where you want notification
- Change rule....
- Display a window alert

It's seems like it is not the real notification box but this is still a workaround...